# How to get Pivot table to use data from a dynamic data set?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the VBA code to recognize a dataset that can change as compared to a set Range like Range(A1:C100)

I am trying to do this for the purposes of automating a pivottable

I understand that we can find the Last Column and Last Row of this dataset, being 3 and 6. I was wondering if it is possible to use range that I want using this information?

Specifically, I think having these steps is required:

- 1) Being able to change the Column(3) to a alphabet so that VBA can understand it
- 2) Being able to convert the last row and last col data into a RANGE form.

**Code**

```
Sub CreatePivot()
' 
' Creates a PivotTable report from the table on Sheet1
' by using the PivotTableWizard method with the PivotFields
' method to specify the fields in the PivotTable.

Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField

' Select the sheet and first cell of the table that contains the data.
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Record").Select 
Range("A3").Select

' Create the PivotTable object based on the Employee data on Sheet1/record
Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard

' Specify row and column fields.
Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Outcome")
objField.Orientation = xlRowField
Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Broker Group")
objField.Orientation = xlColumnField

' Specify a data field with its summary ' function and format.
Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Outcome")
objField.Orientation = xlDataField
objField.Function = xlCount
objField.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

' Specify a page field. '
' Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("GENDER")
' objField.Orientation = xlPageField

' Preview the new PivotTable report.
' ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
' Prompt the user whether to delete the PivotTable.
' Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' If MsgBox("Delete the PivotTable?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
'     ActiveSheet.Delete
' End If
' Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

*Example:*

[image]

Comment: Re your item 1 - I can't think of any situation within VBA where you **have** to use an alphabetic value to specify a column - for instance a `Cells(5, "XY")` can be written as `Cells(5, 649)`, and a `Range("A5", "X10")` (or even `Range("A5:X10")`) can be written as `Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(10, 24))`.  There is almost always a way of avoiding the alphabetic version of a column index.

Comment: share your current code attempt to Automate your PivotTable

Comment: If you format your input as a table, then the Pivot Table would always refer to the full table, no matter how the dimensions if the table changes.

Comment: @ShaiRado I copied some code online that would allow me to do what I need without specifying the lastcol and lastrow like this; code is below

SørenHoltenHansen I am assuming u mean set the datarange as a table right?

YowE3K hey thanks for the tip!


https://anotepad.com/notes/w2xcfh for the code